# XCode iOS Simulator get location buggy?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, core-location

Is it just me or is the iOS Simulator slow when trying to obtain location? It sometimes takes multiple calls to obtain the information.

For example, I'll set location to New York, update my labels to show "New York, NY", change location to Hong Kong, and try to update my labels again, but it takes between 2 and 5 method calls before the labels change to HK.

Is my location code inefficient or is the iOS simulator buggy for these requests?

```
@IBAction func findMyLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    // set location manager, set accuracy and start updating
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location) {
        (let placemarks, let error) in
        if error != nil {
            println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if placemarks.count > 0 && placemarks != nil {
            let placemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            let locationsArray = locations as NSArray
            self.displayLocationInfo(placemark, locations: locationsArray)
        }
    }
}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark, locations: NSArray) {
    // stop updating to save power
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    cityLabel?.text = placemark.locality
    zipcodeLabel?.text = placemark.postalCode
    stateLabel?.text = placemark.administrativeArea
    countryLabel?.text = placemark.country

    if let locationObj = locations.lastObject as? CLLocation {
        let coordinates = locationObj.coordinate
        coordinatesLabel?.text = "\(coordinates.latitude),\(coordinates.longitude)"
    }
}
```

Please post if there are better ways to write my code! I am new to iOS Development!

Comment: I got the same problem :), sometime I have to try 3 or 4 times to set location for simulator. Best solution, use your real device :D

Comment: This seems reasonable to me - in the real world location can take a while to settle down - check the horizontalAccuracy of the locations you receive - you should see it improve over time.